# Oracle - OCI query timeout

Tags: oracle, timeout, prepared-statement, oracle-call-interface

Is there any way to set a timeout on Oracle OCI calls (OCIStmtExecute for example) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way provided by `OCI` itself.

You can create a `Timer` and issue an `OCIBreak()` on timeout.

`OCIBreak()` is thread safe and signal safe.

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts can be set on oracle server side, but not through any OCI APIs.

Comment: How? **********************

Answer (score -1):

PHP's OCI module can do it according to this comment:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php#84144

Comment: No, this is a *connection* timeout, not a timeout on executing a statement as the example in the question asks.